# Complex IIF to SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I am trying to duplicate a complex IIF function I used in MS Access but can't seem to translating it into a SLQ 2008 using CASE.  I am trying to create a WHERE clause something like this

`.....
  WHERE 
  (IIF([Created Date]= NULL, IIF(DATEDIFF(day,[Created Date],[POSTED Date])<=3,1,IIF([Created Date] BETWEEN [Disti Reported Sales Date] AND [Posted Date]),1,NULL)))=1
AND 
......`
Basically what its doing is looking at a date from one column and comparing it to two other columns but if one of the columns is NULL then it uses a different comparison.

Comment: Are you sure that's right? Seems that loosely you are checking that if [Created Date] IS NULL, then perform the date diff on [Created Date] and [POSTED Date], which couldn't return a value < = 3

Comment: You are right was a long night and miss typed it but the concept is the same If the date I want to check against is `Null` then do this test `ELSE` do this test is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation should look close to this:

```
WHERE (CASE
    WHEN [Created Date] IS NULL
    THEN (CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, [Created Date], [POSTED Date]) <= 3 
        THEN 1
        ELSE (CASE
            WHEN [Created Date] BETWEEN [Disti Reported Sales Date] AND [Posted Date]
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
            END)
        END)
    ELSE 0
    END) = 1
```

However, this can be simplified to something like this:

```
WHERE (CASE
    WHEN [Created Date] IS NULL AND DATEDIFF(DD, [Created Date], [POSTED Date]) <= 3 THEN 1
    WHEN [Created Date] IS NULL AND [Created Date] BETWEEN [Disti Reported Sales Date] AND [Posted Date] THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

As noted in my comment, it still seems odd that if [Created Date] IS NULL, you are trying to still use it in any calculation.

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed sorry for the field confusion was a late night.  Here are the tweaks I needed to make as your were assuming the field being tested was `NULL` in both cases.
    `AND(CASE
    WHEN POS.[Disti Reported Sales Order Date] IS NULL AND ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, DB.[Created At], POS.[POS Trans Date])) <= 3 THEN 1
    WHEN POS.[Disti Reported Sales Order Date] IS NOT NULL AND DB.[Created At] BETWEEN POS.[Disti Reported Sales Order Date] AND POS.[POS Trans Date] THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) = 1`